# Separating non convex objects

Tags: image-processing, vision

I seek to separate the objects contained within the following image.
[image]

The green line is the result of using the Magenostatic Active Contour Field: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4359352

The red line is just the morphological skeleton of the binary segmentation. I thought that I could just use the angles between branch points to identify curved structures by selecting the largest angle between adjacent points. However, this was of course a silly thing to do. I am really stuck and have no idea on how to proceed. I have also tried concavity detection using a procedure similar to : http://www.nature.com/articles/srep00503#supplementary-information

The problem being that the objects to be segmented are not convex.

Please help

Cheers
This is the segmentation
[image: This is the segmentation]
This is the image
[image: This is the image]
This is what I would like to end up with
[image: seg]

Comment: Maybe a watershed algorithm <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)> could do it.

Comment: I tried that but it over segments and I cant find suitable markers for marker controlled variants